# A search bar appears, but I CANNOT input text

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, uisearchbar

I tried to create a search bar using react native elements.  When I ran the code, a search bar appeared, but it would not let me type text inside of it.  As a matter of fact, the search bar did not even occupy the top part of the simulator.  It was like the size of a small button. It looked like an icon or still image that would not let me input text. Has this ever happened to anyone?  Below is the code I wrote up.  Anybody know what could be the issue?  I installed RN elements and linked it.  I even NPM installed just for the heck of it and nothing happened. Any help or leads would be appreciated. Here is the link to the search bar I am trying to create: 
https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html#docsNav

```
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

export default SearchBar extends React.Component {
      constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
         search: ""
         };
         updateSearch = search => {
        this.setState({ search });
         };
       }
          render(){
            return(
              <SearchBar
                 containerStyle={{
                 backgroundColor: "white",
                 borderBottomWidth: 1,
                 borderRadius: 1 1
               }}
              inputStyle={{ backgroundColor: "white" }}
              placeholder="Type Here..."
              placeholderTextColor={ "White" }
              onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
              value={search}
              />
             )
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is ,

```
value={search}
```

this should be,

```
value={this.state.search}
```

**Or** you should take state in a variable,

```
render(){
   const { search } = this.state;            
return(
```

**Note:** You have written `updateSearch` method inside of `constructor`, you need to write is outside of `constructor` (if not a typo)

---

This is the example from [link](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html#docsNav) provided by you,

```
import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    search: '',
  };

  updateSearch = search => {         //This function is outside of constructor
    this.setState({ search });
  };

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;   //You missed this

    return (
      <SearchBar
        placeholder="Type Here..."
        onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
        value={search}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to call the value set in your constructor using `this.state.search`